# Byte(dec)/Integer to Byte(hex)

Tags: objective-c, hex, byte, decimal

I have a method that converts integer to two dec Bytes:

```
- (void)intToBytes:(NSInteger *)integer {
    int16_t i = integer;
    Byte b0 = (Byte)(i / 256);
    Byte b1 = (Byte)(i % 256);

    NSLog(@"BYTES: %hhu, %hhu", b0, b1);
}
```

How could I convert those dec Bytes to hex? Or integer to hex Bytes straightaway?

Comment: What do you mean by "hex"?

Comment: Did you read about the string format specifiers that are available? Look at the docs for `NSString stringWithFormat:` and follow the links.

Comment: For example I have an integer = 449. It's bytes dec value is 1 and 193. But I need hex bytes that is 0x01 0xC1.

Comment: "0x01 0xC1" is just a representation. Byte is defined as `UInt8` What's your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSInteger a = 449;
NSString * hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x",(unsigned int)a];
```

Here hex is "1c1"